# Selecting specific point within specific polygon using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select-by-attribute, point-in-polygon, select-by-location

I am using ArcMap.

I have a shapefile points layer, with each point representing either marginal, suboptimal, or optimal conditions. I want to find only the marginal points within a specific polygon from my catchments polygon layer. So far I have been able to select all marginal points, or the wanted polygon, but not the marginal points WITHIN the specified polygon.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

1) Select your polygon of interest - you can do this manually or with one of the selection tools.

2) Select your 'marginal' points using the Select By Attributes tool with the **Method drop-down set to 'Add to current selection'**.

You will now have a selected polygon in one layer and selected points in another layer.

3) Use the Select By Location tool to select all 'marginal' points within your selected polygon by **checking the 'Use selected features' checkbox**.

This will produce a selection of only those point features specified as being 'marginal' within your polygon of interest.

Answer (score 1):

- Select by attributes for Marginal
- select polygons of interest
- select by location

  - make sure the selection method is select from currently selected
    features
  - choose your points in the target layer and your polygon
    layer in the source layer
  - make sure the Use selected features box is checked
  - selection method is target layer is completely within the source layer